# Mechanical disc brake not like it used to be

Tags: disc-brake

So basically, I removed a part from my caliper, the one with a spring in it, that is supposed to push the pad onto the rotor. I removed the cover and the spring popped out. I don't know why I did that, but I somehow managed to put it back. After that the brake is not like it used to be, the lever wont spring back fully, I can press the lever all the way till it hits the grip, but with the front lever that is not the case. I also opened a lever because I wanted to remove the cable so I can easily access to caliper, I put it back but everything seems very wrong.

Any help?

The caliper is a Repute, don't know the exact model.

I'm a 15 y/o kid who knows only some basic things about bikes, so go easy on me :)

Comment: Can you post pictures? That would make it a lot clearer what the problem is. It's probably not too hard to get the bits back together correctly on a mechanical caliper, and after removing the cable you'll need to adjust everything anyway

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this is what's going on, but I suspect it: on a lot of places on bikes where there are return springs (springs that return the action of the part to the starting point, as on a disc brake caliper or a rear derailleur lower cage), the spring needs to be wound up some when installed for it work properly. That pre-tensions it so it snaps back how you want. Otherwise it will still spring back a little when you release the brake lever, but not very crisply or decisively. Also, a spring that wants to pop out like you describe implies that it's wound up and needs to be re-wound when installed.

That you can pull the lever back all the way may be a separate problem, i.e. once the caliper is back together you'll be able to adjust it as normal.

When you're doing all this, be careful when you have the brake pads out to avoid touching the pad surface with bare hands and always avoid contacting it with grease or oil. They're easy to contaminate and then they won't work as well and may squeal.

Comment: Is there even a way i can wound it up again?It seems impossible to put it back like it used ot be, because on the both ends of the spring there is a curved thing that you need to insert in two holes, one in the caliper, and one on the part that you can remove.

Comment: Also, i think it might be something related to cable, maybe the cable is not lubed, so it goes hard, but the bike is quite new so i doubt it

Comment: I would be able to guess better with pictures as I'm kinda shooting in the dark, but on the part you remove that the spring mates with, is it possible to put a turning or twisting motion on it as you reinstall it?